# Redirect Standard Edit page

Tags: outputlink, edit

I have Created visualforce page and using pageblocktable shown contact list of record and every row we have a Edit link and want to redirect to their Standard edit page(contact).

```
 <apex:outputLink value="/?id={!con.id}" target="_blank"> 
                      Edit
 </apex:outputLink>
```

if I'm using above code it will redirect to Home page (Salesforce home tab).

```
 <apex:outputLink value="/e?id={!con.id}" target="_blank"> 
                      Edit
 </apex:outputLink>
```

it shows message url no longer available.

Answer (score 4):

to edit record link should looks like:

```
value="/{!con.id}/e"
```

better solution is to use [URLFOR](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm) and [Action](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_action.htm)

```
value="{!URLFOR($Action.Contact.Edit, con.id, [])}"
```

Comment: Would be better to suggest using [$Action](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_action.htm) global variable as it is more dynamic.